# I want to avoid this warning: "Microsoft Office has identified a potential security concern"

Tags: excel, hyperlink, warnings

I'm following a hyperlink in Excel.  It comes up with the warning above, although the linked file is on my computer. I can override the warning and follow the link, but I want to avoid it.

I put the relevant folder into "Trusted Locations" but it made no difference

Comment: If you go to the target file, right-click > properties, does it have a button in the bottom right that says, "Unblock"?

Comment: No, it didn't have an unblock button.  But I have a solution now, which involved a regedit  - see below

Answer (score 0):

I was given this solution:
open the Registry editor by pressing Windows logo key then pressing R.
When the RUN box opens, type regedit there then click OK.
Then navigate to this path:Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Security
If you do not have the Security key there, that looks like a folder, please create it. If the Security key is there, just add the DWORD (32-bit) Value named DisableHyperlinkWarning then set it to 1.

This worked!